# swiftui save image with mask

Tags: ios, swiftui, mask, photo

I have a picture with a drawn mask everything will display as it should.

```
var imageView: some View {
        Image(uiImage: newImage)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit() 
            .reverseMask({
                DrawShape(drawingPath: drawing)
                        .stroke(lineWidth: 5) // define stroke width
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                
            })
    }
```

When I try to save image to photo image, photo saved without mask

Convert view to image

```
extension View {
    func asImage() -> UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)

        // locate far out of screen
        controller.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: CGFloat(Int.max), width: 1, height: 1)
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(controller.view)

        let size = controller.view.intrinsicContentSize //controller.sizeThatFits(in: UIScreen.main.bounds.size)
        controller.view.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
        controller.view.sizeToFit()

        //let image = controller.view.asImage()
        let image = UIImage(view: controller.view)
        controller.view.removeFromSuperview()
        return image
    }
}
```

Save image

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum( imageView.asImage(), nil, nil, nil)
```

I want to save image with mask but save without mask

Comment: problem was in MASK
Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100).background(.blue)
this worked